# How to validate copy of an element in Angularjs and show error message

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form in which same elements are generated multiple times dynamically.On submitting the form I need to validate this form element and display error message.
Error message is shown with the following code say eg:

```
<span class="error input-icon fui-alert" ng-show="historyForm.edutoDate0.$error.beforeDate"></span>
```

edutoDate input element is generated dynamically with ids edutoDate0,edutoDate1....
But the error messages are not showing.On removing this index values 0,1,2... it will work.Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Can you try get this example into a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can help you debug. There are multiple reasons this might not work. My guess is `historyForm.edutoDate0.$error.beforeDate` is undefind or a bad reference. angular's form model gets it's field names from the name attribute on an input element rather than the ID. Try confirm `edutoDate0` exists. it is most likely an array if they all have the same id or name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  code instead of your code

```
ng-show="historyForm.edutoDate[0].$error.beforeDate">
ng-show="historyForm.edutoDate[1].$error.beforeDate">
ng-show="historyForm.edutoDate[2].$error.beforeDate">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used ng-form directive and resolved the issue.My code is like below.

```
<span ng-repeat="experience in userExperience">
                    <ng-form name="historyExpForm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a ng-click="deleteExperience(experience)" data-action="close" class="delete">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                        </a>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
                            <label>Position</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="experience.title"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
                            <label>Organisation/Company</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="experience.organization"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
                            <label>From date</label>
                            <input type="text" name="expFromDate" class="form-control" ng-model="experience.fromDate" ui-date />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
                            <label>To date</label>
                            <div class="form-group has-success">
                                <input type="text" name="expToDate" class="form-control" ng-model="experience.toDate" ui-date before-date="{{experience.fromDate | date:'dd MMM, y hh:mm a'}}"/>
                                <span class="error input-icon fui-alert" ng-show="historyExpForm.expToDate.$error.beforeDate"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="separator"/>
                </ng-form>
                </span>
```

beforeDate directive will validate each subform and show error message properly.